# Не могу получить всех участников беседы VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Написал код который в итоге выдаёт количество участников беседы, но выдаёт не полное количество участников, выдаёт 2963 и 2946, но в беседах больше 3000 участников, 2 беседы вообще заполнены целиком т.е. 7000 участников. Токены получаю ставлю все галочки. Может в CallBack нужно ещё что-то выбрать? Так-же в вк API выбран тоже последний 5.154
Помогите пожалуйста, 2й день колупаюсь, никак не могу разобраться, гугл не помог, чат GPT так-же по кругу гоняет и ничего толкового не предлагает

```
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# Загрузка переменных окружения
load_dotenv()

# Конфигурация
VK_API_VERSION = '5.154'
VK_API_URL = 'https://api.vk.com/method/'
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv("VK_GROUP_ACCESS_TOKEN")  # Ваш API токен
PEER_ID = 2000000000 + 1  # Ваш идентификатор беседы


def get_conversation_members(peer_id, offset=0, count=200):
   params = {
       'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN,
       'v': VK_API_VERSION,
       'peer_id': peer_id,
       'offset': offset,
       'count': count,
   }
   response = requests.get(f"{VK_API_URL}messages.getConversationMembers", params=params).json()
   return response


def get_all_conversation_members(peer_id):
   offset = 0
   count = 200  # Максимальное количество участников за один запрос
   total_count = 0

   while True:
       response = get_conversation_members(peer_id, offset=offset, count=count)

       if 'error' in response:
           print(f"Error: {response['error']['error_msg']}")
           return

       total_count += len(response['response']['items'])

       print(f"Collected so far: {total_count} members")

       if total_count >= response['response']['count']:
           break

       offset += count

   print(f"Total members: {total_count}")


# Получение информации о всех участниках
get_all_conversation_members(PEER_ID)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всё банально просто, как ответила поддержка VK, этот метод может отдать только 3000 пользователей, хотя беседы вмещают 7000 пользователей.